# Как взять числа с разных массивов сделать с ними вычесления?

Tags: javascript

У меня уже котёл свистит. Помогите пожалуйста)

```html
var testResults = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
    58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
    34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
    69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
    46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
    41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 41]


var costs = [.25, .27, .25, .25, .25, .25,
    .33, .31, .25, .29, .27, .22,
    .31, .25, .25, .33, .21, .25,
    .25, .25, .28, .25, .24, .22,
    .20, .25, .30, .25, .24, .25,
    .25, .25, .27, .25, .26, .26]






function bestresult(testResults) {
    var highScore = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
        conclusion = ('Тест №' + i + '=' + testResults[i])  //ввывели результаты всех 36 тестов
        console.log(conclusion)


        if (testResults[i] > highScore) {
            highScore = testResults[i]
        }
    }
    return highScore
}

function alltest(testResults) {
    var allTest = testResults.length;
    return allTest
}

function alltestFunc() {
    var allTest = alltest(testResults);
    return allTest
}

function getBest(testResults, highScore) {
    var besttests = []
    for (i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
        if (testResults[i] == highScore) {
            besttests.push(i)
        }

    }
    return besttests;
}





var allTest = alltestFunc()
var highScore = bestresult(testResults)
var besttests = getBest(testResults, highScore)



console.log('Всего проверенных препаратов:' + ' ' + allTest)
console.log('Максимальный результат = ' + highScore)
console.log('Максимальные результаты вышли у препаратов №: ' + besttests)



function bestformulas(testResults) {
    var tteesstt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
        var ttt = testResults[i] / costs[i]

        if (tteesstt < ttt) {

            tteesstt = ttt
        }
    }
    return tteesstt;
}


var tttt = bestformulas(testResults)
console.log(tttt)
```

Не работает только последняя функция. В кратце, нужно взять 2 числа из 2 разных массивов(с 1 индексом) и разделить 1 число на другое и из всех этих вычислений, выбрать наибольшее и вывести его в консоль. Уже часа 1.5 разбираю эту часть кода и не понимаю почему выходит какое-то непонятное число.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для людей, кто не любит гадать, придумали отладку кода

Comment: А не нужно ли вторым аргументом передать costs?

Comment: я если честно не знаю как делать отладку кода. я только учусь)

Comment: в дубликате написано как искать ошибки в т.ч. с помощью отладки

Comment: я ставил 2 аргумент costs, выходит другое число, но оно тоже никак не может подходить